# Preventing the user from deleting in an input field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a text field (`<input>` in HTML) that the user can only use to write text, but when deleting the text, it should prevent him from updating the state of the input element.

```html
<input type="text" />
```

I couldn't come up with a solution except to detect the user key presses on the keyboard, i.e, using the `onKeyUp` attribute, and watch the user keystrokes until he presses the Backspace character:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  const keyCode = e.keyCode
  if (keyCode === 8) console.log("Backspace pressed!")
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

However, there's a missing part here, even though the user won't be able to clear the input content by the Backspace key, he can instead use the `Del` key.
So I would have then to handle the Del key the same way I handle the Backspace key.

Now, there's another problem, which is trying to modify the input content by overwriting the content as follows:

[image]

and then, after that, I will have to prevent the user from editing the text by `cutting` the content (which I have no idea how to do).

So, what are the alternatives?

Please feel free to use HTML, JavaScript, CSS.

---

If you're using React, I was able to solve this problem simply by checking if the length of the input value is shorter than the one being memorized in the state, then prevent the user from updating the state:

The answer resides between controlling the value prop (or attribute if you wish) and the onChange handler.

```js
const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState('')
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value
  if(value.length < inputVal.length) return // prevent modifications
  setInputVal(value)
}
return <input value={inputVal} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Now, the question is, how to do the same when using only HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: Your exact requirements are unclear.

Comment: @connexo, the requirement is simple, write only, you can't go back.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: why are you only allowing users to enter a string of increasing length? There are many ways to circumvent the restrictions you will put in place: (1) user can paste a shorter string, (2) user can use dev tools to forcibly reassign the value of the element. The question is, what are you trying to achieve, and if there is a better way to achieve that?

Comment: @Terry, actually no, and it's not related to security at all. I know that someone could open the dev tools and play with it, it doesn't matter, what matter is that the field shouldn't be modified because it should only be written by a barcode scanner. What this question shows is a one side of the problem, and the rest of the scenario is already in my code editor. 

Comment: what is your use case to prevent the user from deleting the input text value?

Comment: @Sheldeeb, the text field must only include what the barcode scanner reads, the user might mistakenly write on the input, or mistakenly deletes from the input. what the barcode scanner reads is something like this QR-XXXXXX-QR the first QR and the last QR are used to _unlock_ and _lock_ the text field when the QR code scanner attempts to write on the text field input, ---- there are multiple places where the QR field exists on the Control Panel I'm building, generally it works the same way everywhere, except here, I want to allow the user to write _after_ the read QR, but not before.

Comment: anyway, I added an easy answer that should works good with your different sitiuations

Comment: Show the code that sets the value from the barcode scan.

Comment: also, you can make the input disabled for the user

Comment: this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/73874605/12577650

Comment: @Sheldeeb OP wants to allow adding text at the end of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this? Then it doesn't matter what they press.

```
const input = document.querySelector('input')
let previousState = input.value;
input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if ( previousState.length > input.value.length ) input.value = previousState;
  previousState = input.value;
})
```

Comment: though you still can't count on it 100%, since they can paste something in that's longer than the value already there. you'd have to ensure the previous state is included in the new value with only one letter added or some such to be 100%.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I can imagine a use case for it. i've seen a writing app that doesn't let you edit while you are writing so that you get into the flow (writing your novel or short story or whatever). so who knows. of course, you wouldn't use an input for that.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos, I know exactly what I'm doing. 

Answer (score 1):

@dqhendricks answer is in the right way, but misses some possibilities:

1. User can hit backspace (reduce length by one) (covered)
2. User can select a piece of text and hit backspace or other key (covered)
3. User can select a piece (or all text) and replace by a different string with same length. (Not covered)

So my suggestion is:

> You should listen for change event, then compare the previous string, if the new string starts with the previous string, it's ok. Otherwise we revert the change.

In code ir should look like:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

let previousState = input.value; // initial state

input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (!input.value.startsWith(previousState)) {
    input.value = previousState; // revert change
  }
  previousState = input.value;
})
```

Comment: I'm writing on mobile, hope someone could convert the code into a code snippet so we can validade it. Also please ignore some typo.

Comment: copy paste these three lines in squence: 
```<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<!-- language: lang-js -->
### YOUR CODE ###
<!-- end snippet -->```

Answer (score 1):

In the keydown event, put whatever keycodes you want in an array and see if the current keycode is included. Then create a select event, and blur the input when it fires.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if ([8, 46].includes(e.keyCode)) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})

input.addEventListener('select', (e) => {
  e.target.blur()  
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: New Idea, thanks for investing +1

Answer (score 0):

you can check the length of the input's value, if it became shorter replace it with the previous value

```
let value;
input.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
  if(value && input.value.length < value.length) input.value=value;
  else value=input.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have some piece of code that sets the value from the barcode scanner. Once that is being set, also do `input.dataset.barcodeValue="scanresult"`.

Then to make it sufficiently difficult for a regular user to ruin the barcode, you need to prevent several things:

- pasting
- cutting
- typing over the barcode value
- dragging text into the input
- pressing delete or backspace which would mess up the barcode value.

All of this is covered in the `input` event.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#bc-value');

function setValueFromBarcodeScanner(val) {
  input.value = input.dataset.barcodeValue = val;
  input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const { barcodeValue } = input.dataset;
    if (barcodeValue && !input.value.startsWith(barcodeValue)) input.value = barcodeValue;
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="bc-value" />
<button type="button" onclick="setValueFromBarcodeScanner('433-224-221-456')">Set value from Barcode Scanner</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you:

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById('write-only-input');
let lastValue = '';

inputElement.oninput = function(e) {
  if (inputElement.value.startsWith(lastValue)) {
    lastValue = inputElement.value;
  } else {
    inputElement.value = lastValue;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="write-only-input" />
```